# DNS leak on Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, vpn, dns

I run a VPN on my local PC before running my Android emulator (MEmu). This successfully changes my IP, but my DNS remains the same as the exact DNS on my local PC.

I would like to know how I can block or change the DNS on my Android emulator so it matches the one from my VPN/proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can set the DNS server if you configure a static IP. This can easily be done in the wireless settings.

I don't know how your emulator connects to the network (cellular or WiFi). If it's using WiFi, you can go to *wireless and networking* options, *Wifi settings*, *More*, *Advanced*, and finally *Use Static IP*. Now you can set your static IP and the DNS server. This will not work if your emulator uses a cellular connection.

If you don't want to set a static IP you can use third-party apps like [DNSset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dnset), though it might not be the right app because it will open a separate VPN connection. However, [Dns Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.emrekoc.dnschanger) might work. Simply enter your DNS server in the dns server field and press *DNS* to accept the change.

Comment: thanks, you didn't really explain how I would go about changing the dns server through static ip or dnsset in my android emulator